# Automatically fill data from sheet 1 to sheet 2

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a "working days" Excel file with two sheets.
In the 1st sheet I had three columns with type, surname and department (of employees), the days and date of the month. Below the days-dates columns, I "check" the days that employees are working with the number "1" (it could be a tick).

[image: Input example]

Is it possible, when I check in the sheet 1 an employee at a specific date with number "1" (or tick), to automatically fill, in the 2nd sheet, the data from type, surname and department in each column (sheet 1 B,C,D to sheet 2 B,C,D and E,F,G)?

[image: Output example]

Answer (score 0):

Since I see you only want to see "Employees" and their "Managers", I created a few formulas for them. I am not sure how would I make it work with "Head managers".

<sub>(Note: change `Sheet1` with your actual 1st sheet name. Use single quotes if your sheet has spaces, e.g. `'1st sheet'`)</sub>

**`B3`** (<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the formula):

```
="Manager"
```

**`C3`** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the *array* formula):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(1,(Sheet1!B:B=Sheet1!$B3)*(Sheet1!D:D=$G3),0)),"")
```

**`D3`** (<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the formula):

```
=IFERROR(Sheet1!$G3,"")
```

**`E3`** (<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the formula):

```
="Employee"
```

**`F3`** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the *array* formula):

```
=IFERROR(
 INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,
       MATCH(1,(1=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(1,MATCH($A3,Sheet1!$5:$5,0))
                           &":"&ADDRESS(1048576,MATCH($A3,Sheet1!$5:$5,0))))
               *(Sheet1!$B:$B=Sheet1!$E3),0)),"")
```

**`G3`** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the *array* formula):

```
=IFERROR(
 INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$D,
       MATCH(1,(1=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(1,MATCH($A3,Sheet1!$5:$5,0))
                           &":"&ADDRESS(1048576,MATCH($A3,Sheet1!$5:$5,0))))
               *(Sheet1!$B:$B=Sheet1!$E3),0)),"")
```

**Results:**
[image: results]

Comment: First of all, thank you for answer! For the Head Managers, it could be HeadManager. I don't know if I helped you...

Comment: I don't know if you understand what I want to do... When I write the number 1 (or another number, symbol, etc) to E7 of Sheet1, I want to automatically fill the B3-C3-D3 of Sheet2 with the data of B7-C7-D7 of Sheet1.

Comment: What about E3, F3, G3 of sheet2 ? These formulas fill those too, together with B3, C3, D3.

Comment: The E3, F3, G3 of sheet2 have to automatically fill by B17, C17, E17 of sheet1. Could they?

Comment: Man... It seems you have not checked the answer at all. Yes, all the cells in sheet2 are updated automatically. When you input `1` in the sheet1, then this employee appears automatically on sheet2 together with his manager. But I am too busy now to make this work for Head managers. You have the formulas. You are on a good path. Now it's time for you to do the work.

Comment: Thank you a lot my friend and as you said: it's time for me to do the work! ;)

Comment: Hi again my friend! I tried to insert the formulas, but everything "crashed"! I believe that I didn't do the things right. Sorry for the inconvenience, but is it easy for you to explain how to make those formulas work?

Comment: Again, this only gives you employees and managers. Please be more specific than "everything crashed". This does not give me information. Were you able to fill in array formulas correctly? So that you have curly braces `{=...}` around your formulas? Use Ctrl+Shift+Return. Manually typing curly braces does not work.

Comment: When I'm saying that "everything crashed" I mean that when I put a formula to Sheet2 and hit Return or Ctrl+Shift+Return for array, I saw a pop up window with corrections like: "Not trying to type a formula?
When the first character is an equal (=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula:

• you type:   =1+1, cell shows:   2

To get around this, type an apostrophe ( ' ) first:

• you type:   '=1+1, cell shows:   =1+1"

Comment: As far as I can tell, the formulas are complete. You don't need apostrophes, you need formulas... Maybe your system's separator is not comma, but semicolon? In such case you would need to change every comma for a semicolon.